# What is the meaning of MigrateFeatures in UpgradeVersion?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade, migrate

I see no difference between [MigrateFeatures](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/upgradeversion.html) with the value `yes` or `no`. Can anyone tell me which effect has this flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, WiX is just an abstraction of the underlying Windows Installer (MSI).  The MSDN doco for MSI covers it pretty well here:

[MigrateFeatureStates Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370034(v=vs.85).aspx)

The way it works is lets say MSI v1 has features:

A  installed by default, user left it selected

B  installed by default, user selected not to install

If MSI v2 had the same feature tree and MigrateFeatures was not selected, Features A and B would both be installed by default.  If it was selected then A would be installed by default and B wouldn't.   The choice has been "migrated".

The problem is if you add feature C.  Because it wasn't installed in v1 it won't get installed by default in v2.   You can work around this with some authoring to select it at runtime.

Comment: Because I have only an "all" feature without selection this flag has no relevance for me. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you don't set it and later add a new feature.  As always, be sure to test your upgrades.